# isomorphic localization of finitely presented modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be commutative ring with unit and M,N be two finitely presented modules over $A$. I want to show that if $M_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong N_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ then there exists $f \in A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_f \cong N_f$.

I know the following results :

$Hom_{A_\mathfrak{p}}(M_\mathfrak{p},N_\mathfrak{p}) \cong Hom_A(M,N)_\mathfrak{p}$

and

$M_\mathfrak{p} =0$ implies that there exists $f \in A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_f = 0$.

Here is the idea I have :

Suppose $g : M_\mathfrak{p} \to N_\mathfrak{p}$ is an isomorphism then lift $g$ to a morphism $g' : M \to N$ then $\ker(g')_\mathfrak{p} = 0$ and coker$(g')_\mathfrak{p}=0$ then there exist $f_1,f_2 \in A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ such that $\ker(g')_{f_1} = 0$ and coker$(g')_{f_2}=0$. Take $f=f_1f_2$ then $\ker(g')_{f} = 0$ and coker$(g')_{f}=0$ which means that $g'_f : M_f \to N_f$ gives an isomorphism.

My question is : is this approach valid (i'm not sure about the reasonning at the end) and if yes how can we obtain the lift $g'$ ? If not how do we prove the result ?

In fact I am more generally interested in the following statement : a finitely presented $A$ module is projective if and only if there exist $f_1,...,f_n \in A$ with $f_1 + ... + f_n =1$ and $M_{f_i} \cong A_{f_i}^{n_i}$. A reference would be fine (great even).

Comment: This is a common theorem in commmutative algebra often under the heading of "local freeness". You can find this result on Pete L Clark's notes (on page 136) http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf

Comment: Done. Also, did you ever figure out why K. Conrad needed to pass to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for the other question--why he didn't just use the same method in $\mathbb{Q}$? The argument seems to work without qualification.

Comment: Nope but now I'm very much convinced that you were right (arguments works over $\mathbb{Q}$). I haven't read the whole document though so maybe he uses the result somewhere over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the OP's request, here is a reference that shows the result, a result often associated with the words "local freeness" for its applications in algebraic geometry. See:

[Pete L. Clark's CA Notes, Page 137, Theorem 7.21](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)